How can I teach, how to replace 'unless' with 'if not'?
This is my first time teaching from Stan Baronett's Logic (5 ed, 2022). For brevity, let "president" be POTUS. How do I teach these 2 difficulties to high schoolers?

In order to translate the statement “A citizen cannot be president unless the citizen
is at least 35 years old,” we need to understand how the word “unless” gets translated.
In most statements, the word “unless” means if not. Substituting this into the original
statement gives us this result: ⚠ “A citizen cannot be president if the citizen is not at least
35 years old.”

Baronett skipped a step at ⚠, as direct substitution yields

A citizen can't be POTUS if not the citizen is $\ge 35$. $\tag{2}$

Why can't you  leave the "not" here in (2)? And Baronett fails to spell out how (2) becomes

A citizen can't be POTUS if the citizen
is not $\ge 35$. $\tag{3}$

What justifies you to move "not", to between "is" and "$\ge 35$"?

Please don't use MathJax to create colored text (particularly if you are going to use green and red text, which is bad for those with the most common form of color blindness).  The site theme is constructed to work in light- and dark-modes, and manually changing the colors can mess with the readability in certain contexts.  Also, the typesetting of mathematics is different from the rest of the typesetting, and screen readers (i.e. for the blind) handle mathematics differently.  In general, it is best to stick to the defaults.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4955360/why-if-not-the-citizen-is-%e2%89%a5-35-%e2%89%a1-if-the-citizen-is-not-%e2%89%a5-35

https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/28013/how-can-middle-school-students-intuit-if-not-except-if

In general, "not (object A satisfies condition B)" is the same as "object A does not satisfy condition B."
Or, more simply, "not (A is B)" is the same as "A is not B."
Why? I'm pretty sure that's just by definition.
In general, "not (A relation B)" is the same as "A not-relation B."

Indeed. Perhaps a subliminal issue is that rewriting standard logical expressions into normal (reasonably precise) English syntax does often change word order...

In natural language though, one can get into troubles with this. "The colour of golf is not blue" should be interpreted as "not(the colour of golf is blue)" because the sport golf does not have a colour. But to parse it as "the colour of golf is not(blue)" seems to say that golf does have a colour, it's just not blue.

I don't understand your argument, but consider that the rules states:

A citizen cannot be president unless the citizen is at least 35 years old.

Q: What if a citizen is NOT at least 35 years old?
A: The citizen cannot be president.
This would translate:

IF a citizen is NOT at least 35 years old, THEN the citizen cannot be
president.

Note that the given rule, on its own, does not tell us anything about when a citizen is at least 35. He or she may or may not qualify to be president depending on several other rules not stated here. (See edit below.)

Here is an example of another form of the "A unless B" construct:

I am at the beach unless it is Sunday.

From this, we infer:

If it is not Sunday, then I am at the beach.

If it is Sunday, then I am NOT at the beach.


This would translate:
I am at the beach XOR it is Sunday.

EDIT
Back to the eligibility problem...
Suppose anyone is eligible unless not ALL qualifications met.
Define logical propositions: Eligible and AllMet
We have:
Eligible unless not AllMet
Not AllMet implies not Eligible
And also...
AllMet implies Eligible
We conclude:
AllMet XOR Eligible

There seems to be some ambiguity in the meaning of P unless Q. It could be simply mean not Q implies not P. In addition, depending on the context, it may also mean that Q implies P.


"I don't understand your argument" Why not? Daniel Collins understood my question ----- "(2) "if not" is not literally grammatical English and led to your confusion"

I suggest that the meaning was meant to be "if... not" (as opposed to literally "if not"), similar to how an if-then clause actually looks like "if... then" (with some other expression in the ellipses and after). OP's statement (2) is simply not grammatically valid English.
Better and more customary, I think, would be to present the meaning in terms of the basic if-then conditional; $p \implies q$ can also be expressed as $q \text{ unless } \lnot p$ (e.g., as in Rosen, Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, Sec. 1.1, Definition 5). In other words, $q \text { unless } p$ translates to $\lnot p \implies q$.
Overall, the quality of this book looks a bit sketchy.

"the quality of this book looks a bit sketchy." Please elaborate why?

@Eth: Based on the one paragraph: (1) Skipping steps is not good. (2) "if not" is not literally grammatical English and led to your confusion. (3) The author seems to avoid a symbolic presentation which makes these things clearer. (4) It's at odds with the standard presentation that $p \implies q$ is equivalent to $q \text { unless } \lnot p$.
